# How to calculate voltage and current?

Tags: voltage-regulator

I recently purchased a S111733PI voltage regulator.

I'm trying to step down 12VDC to 3.3VDC.

The data sheet suggests the use of R1 and R2. They can be selected once I know Vadj and Iadj.  How do I get the value of Vadj and Iadj?

The circuit diagram with formula is shown below. In the data sheet they've tested it only till 7V input, but it also suggests that the IC can handle 16V input max.

[Link To The Datasheet](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/dlmain/Datasheets-6/DSA-114078.pdf)

[image: Circuit Diagram from the Datasheet]

Comment: Link to data sheet is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at a bad datasheet. Try this one:

http://www.bg-electronics.de/datenblaetter/Schaltkreise/S1117-XXPI.pdf

You are trying to use the schematic for the adjustable regulator when you are actually using a fixed 3.3volt regulator. The datasheet that you linked to has those figures incorrect. You don't need any resistors at all.

(wow, that's the third time in a row that I've been beat by a minute.)

Comment: I did see this first. This didn't help. I tried it without resistors and I was getting 0.08V as output with the IC heating up excessively.

Comment: Well then, maybe you have the adjustable one when you really need the fixed one. Is there a part number on the device?

Comment: This is all that it has " AUK A2 S111733PI"

Comment: That's the part number for the fixed 3.3 volt version. It should not have resistors, and shouldn't work correctly without a hard ground.

Comment: Ok I'm guessing I've received a defective IC. I'll purchase a new one and find out.

Answer (score 0):

Iadj is 55 uA nominal and Vajd should be 1.25 V but the datasheet isn't really your friend since you have to read between the lines for S1117A. You have bought the adjustable version, right? Because S1117-33 gives you 3.3 V and reqires no external resistors.

Comment: Without the resistors it just doesn't work. The IC I have says " AUK A2 S11733PI" thats it.

Comment: @Mark beat me to it. See above.